# What happens when process.exit(); used in nodejs program?

Tags: node.js

What is literally happening to a nodejs application when process.exit() is used.

"Nodejs is just a host for some JavaScript". How does this phrase can be elobrated.

What is the basic interpretation that the nodejs is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Brief Overview:**

The `process.exit()` method will terminate the script/process that was started by Node on the machine that it's running on. In other words, for Node to do its thing, a node process has to initiate. This is typically done by running `node some-script.js` from the command line. This process could simply execute a script and exit immediately afterwards, or it could be a long running process like a daemon, server, etc, which requires you to manually exit (i.e. CTRL + C). Sometimes having the user manually exit, is not ideal, so the program could use Node's `process.exit()` to essentially do the equivalent of the user manually exiting.

Additionally, you can pass in error codes to `process.exit(ERROR_CODE)`, which allows the program to communicate with other programs whether or not it was successful.

**What Literally Happens:**

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)...

> ... calling process.exit() will force the
>   process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still
>   asynchronous operations pending that have not yet completed fully,
>   including I/O operations to process.stdout and process.stderr.

So as mentioned in the brief overview, it is literally trying to terminate the Node process (responsible for that script) on your machine — refusing to consider most consequences.

**Caveats:**

- One has to be careful with when/where `process.exit()` is used, for more
  information please read [this](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code).
- Some Node versions have an issue on [windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3584), and one should consider using an [abstraction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exit) instead of `process.exit()` if the aim is to be cross platform.

Comment: That was a good enough information on node's process, According to my understanding from your above explanation and my reading, We start a "server process" in the cloud and leave it running days to gather we never stop it. The requests hits and the concerned function is run by the application.  As far as my knowledge server is the only process that i started from my begin. For more clear understanding Can you list me some process we tend to kill in between purposefully.

Comment: Great :)
I'm not sure I can give you a list of use cases as I personally haven't had too many reasons to use it, and for the most part, I [avoid it](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/02/04/maintainable-node-js-javascript-avoid-process-exit/). So I would suggest you open another question asking for more use cases. But two of the main reasons I use it, is for when I don't want to throw exceptions but still exit the program, and also for when I want to exit the program with an arbitrary exit code that is meaningful to whatever I am doing (i.e. exit code: 123). I hope that helps.

Comment: Okie i would also prefer starting a new thread for that question.Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

From doc "The process.exit() method instructs Node.js to terminate the process as quickly"
If you don't use params default is 0 (exit with code 0)
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit